# Playframwork 2 subproject library with dependencies on play dependency's

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies

I want to split up my play 2.2 project into a couple subprojects. I'm not (yet) trying to split the routes file, but I want a "util" library.
I need to use play dependencies (for example play.api.Logger).

I'm using a Build.scala file with this subproject:

```
lazy val core = Project("core",
  file("core"),
  settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    // ...
  )
)

play.Project(.....).dependsOn(core)
```

How do I add some, or all of play dependencies to the "core" subproject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
lazy val core: Project = Project("core",
  file("core"),
  settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % play.core.PlayVersion.current % "provided"

    )
  )
)
```

The `% "provided"` bit seems to work, so I guess that is better to use.

There probably is no easy way to pick some of the dependencies, unless you list them with their versions.